# Is this vulnerable to mass assignment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, security, mass-assignment

I use this to allow users to vote on an Entry:

```
 <% form_tag url_for(entry_votes_path(@entry)), :id => 'voting_form', :remote => true do %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag 'vote[user_id]', current_user.id  %>
      <%= submit_tag 'Vote for this entry', :id => 'voting_button' %>
 <% end %>
```

This is my controller code:

```
def create
    @entry = Entry.find(params[:entry_id])
    @vote = @entry.votes.build(params[:vote])

    respond_to do |format|
    if @vote.save
        format.html { redirect_to @entry }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

I have two questions

1. How can I assign `current_user.id` without using a hidden field?
2. Also, I'm not using `attr_accessible` or `attr_protected` on the Vote model right now. How should I secure the model to make sure someone can't create a lot of votes? Right now, all the fields in the Vote model are set by the `params` hash -- should I use `attr_protected` on say, the `entry_id` foreign key and then set it separately in the controller?

Comment: Why don't you just merge current_user into the params when you build the vote? Is the user's session invalid at this point?

Comment: No, but I'm not sure of the syntax since I'm building the vote with the entry instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not using attr_accessible
>   or attr_protected on the Vote model
>   right now...

Then, by definition, mass assignment is possible from the query string.

> Should I use attr_protected on say,
>   the entry_id foreign key and then set
>   it separately in the controller?

In general, it's better to use attr_accessible than attr_protected.  This is because attr_accessible establishes a default of deny-all to mass assignment and lets you define whitelisted exceptions.  On the other hand, attr_protected forces you to blacklist specific attributes.  When you modify the program and add a new attribute with attr_accessible set, the program will fail if you need to whitelist the attribute and forget.  In other words, it fails safely.  Alternatively, if you add a new attribute with attr_protected set, the program will work *even if the new attribute should have been included in the blacklist*.  On other words, it fails insecurely.

The rule here is to protect any attribute which it would be dangerous to allow to be set from the query string.  Protecting the key helps prevent injection of new rows but it may be necessary to protect other fields if you want to prevent the ability to change the contents of *existing* rows.

A good reference on this may be found at [guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment).

Comment: So, if I add `attr_accessible` only to the safe options (which, would be all except "entry_id" ... then in the controller, how do I set and save the "entry_id" outside of the params hash?

Comment: The section 6.1 of the guide linked above shows attributes being set explicitly.  Since you are disallowing users to set the attribute directly from the hash, presumably you would check the hash value, validate it and then apply the validated value to the attribute.